# AWK loops test on local vm

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to understand this difference of 5 seconds between 1000 and 10000 loops extracted from gawk article. Would appreciate your help.

```
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f
# how long does it take to do a few loops?
BEGIN {
    LOOPS=100;
# do the test twice
    start=systime();
    for (i=0;i<LOOPS;i++) {
    }
    end = systime();
# calculate how long it takes to do a dummy test
    do_nothing = end-start;
# now do the test again with the *IMPORTANT* code inside
    start=systime();
    for (i=0;i<LOOPS;i++) {
# How long does this take?
        while ("date" | getline) {
            date = $0;
        }
        close("date");
    }
    end = systime();
    newtime = (end - start) - do_nothing;

    if (newtime <= 0) {
        printf("%d loops were not enough to test, increase it\n", 
            LOOPS);
        exit;
    } else {
        printf("%d loops took %6.4f seconds to execute\n", 
            LOOPS, newtime);
        printf("That's %10.8f seconds per loop\n", 
            (newtime)/LOOPS);
# since the clock has an accuracy of +/- one second, what is the error
        printf("accuracy of this measurement = %6.2f%%\n",
            (1/(newtime))*100);
    }
    exit;
}
[root@krislasnetwork ~]# ./testSpeed.sh
1000 loops took 2.0000 seconds to execute
That's 0.00200000 seconds per loop
accuracy of this measurement =  50.00%
[root@krislasnetwork ~]# vi testSpeed.sh # changing loops from 1000 to 10000
[root@krislasnetwork ~]# ./testSpeed.sh
10000 loops took 15.0000 seconds to execute
That's 0.00150000 seconds per loop
accuracy of this measurement =   6.67%
```

It appears that each loop during the 10,000 loops is executed faster than each loop during the 1,000. Can you help me understand this behavior?

Comment: 15 seconds is not less than 2 seconds.

Comment: @Barmar I re-structured his last sentence as it seems he is questioning why the time isn't linear going from 1,000 to 10,000 iterations.

Comment: Since you only have 1-second precision, 2 seconds could actually be the rounded-off value of 1.54 seconds, while 15 seconds could be 15.4. Those are the same per-loop times.

Comment: You're also measuring wall time, not CPU time. Many things can add to wall time.

Comment: Why don't you use the `time` command to get more precise timing?

Comment: It appears the systime() return the current time as the number of seconds since the system epoch but I think this answers my question:

Since you only have 1-second precision, 2 seconds could actually be the rounded-off value of 1.54 seconds, while 15 seconds could be 15.4. Those are the same per-loop times.

Comment: Kristian, I think you've got it now. If you're running on Linux or similar, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55358991/create-timestamp-with-fractional-seconds which explains how to get a timer with sub-second resolution. In summary, add: @load "time" before your BEGIN section, and replace systime() with gettimeofday().